# Counting occurrences in list of dicts

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, count

I have a long list of dicts in the following structure:

```
links = [{'key1': 'dynamic_value', 'validlink': ['link1','link2','link3']}, {'key1': 'dynamic_value', 'validlink': ['link1','link2','link3']}]
```

I need to count how many values the validlink array holds for each key1 value(changing value).

I tried playing with a few counting approaches with no luck.
Thanks!

Edit:
Apparently, my original json wasn't valid.
After fixing the structure, a simple 'len' now works:

```
for l in links:
    validcount = len(l['validlink'])
    print(validcount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after? A more concrete example will be useful.

```
data = [{'key1': 'A', 'validlink': ['A','AA']}, {'key1': 'B', 'validlink': ['B']}]

for a in data:
   print('Key:', a['key1'], 'Count:', len(a['validlink']))
```